# What is the general practice for express and react based application. Keeping the server and client code in same or different projects/folders?

Tags: reactjs, express, client-server

I am from a microsoft background where I always used to keep server and client applications in separate projects.

Now I am writing a client-server application with express as back-end and react js as front-end. Since i am totally a newbie to these two tools, I would like to know..

what is the general practice?:

keeping the express(server) code base and react(client) code base as separate projects? or keeping the server and client code bases together in the same project? I could not think of any pros & cons of either of these approaches.

Your valuable recommendations are welcome!.

PS: please do not mark this question as opinionated.. i believe have a valid reason to ask for recommendations.

Answer (score 4):

I would prefer keeping the server and client as separate projects because that way we can easily manage their dependencies, dev dependencies and unit tests files.

Also if in case we need to move to a different framework for front end at later point we can do that without disturbing the server.

Answer (score 2):

In my opinion, it's probably best to have separate projects here. But you made me think a little about the "why" for something that seems obvious at first glance, but maybe is not.

My expectation is that a project should be mostly organized one-to-one on building a single type of target, whether that be a website, a mobile app, a backend service. Projects are usually an expression of all the dependencies needed to build or otherwise output one functioning, standalone software component. Build and testing tools in the software development ecosystem are organized around this convention, as are industry expectations.

Even if you could make the argument that there are advantages to monolithic projects that generate multiple software components, you are going against people's expectations and that creates the need for more learning and communication. So all things being equal, it's better to go with a more popular choice.

Other common disadvantages of monolithic projects:

- greater tendency for design to become tightly coupled and brittle
- longer build times (if using one "build everything" script)
- takes longer to figure out what the heck all this code in the project is!

It's also quite possible to make macro-projects that work with multiple sub-projects, and in a way have the benefits of both approaches. This is basically just some kind of build script that grabs the output of sub-project builds and does something useful with them in a combination, e.g. deploy to a server environment, run automated tests.

Finally, all devs should be equipped with tools that let them hop between discreet projects easily. If there are pains to doing this, it's best to solve them without resorting to a monolothic project structure.

Some examples of practices that help with developing React/Node-based software that relies on multiple projects:

- The IDE easily supports editing multiple projects. And not in some cumbersome "one project loaded at a time" way.
- Projects are deployed to a repository that can be easily used by npm or yarn to load in software components as dependencies.
- Use "npm link" to work with editable local versions of sub-projects all at once. More generally, don't require a full publish and deploy action to have access to sub-projects you are developing along with your main React-based project.
- Use automated build systems like Jenkins to handle macro tasks like building projects together, deploying, or running automated tests.
- Use versioning scrupulously in package.json. Let each software component have it's own version# and follow the semver convention which indicates when changes may break compatibility.
- If you have a single team (developer) working on front and back end software, then set the dependency versions in package.json to always get the latest versions of sub-projects (packages).
- If you have separate teams working on front and backend software, you may want to relax the dependency version to be major version#s only with semver range in package.json. (Basically, you want some protection from breaking changes.)